# Regex: excluding results based on non capture group?

Tags: python, regex, string, validation

So I'm trying to use the following regex to match patterns of *valid* prices

```
^\$[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\,\d{3})?(?:\.\d{2})?
```

(derived from another question here on SO)

Constraints for matching being:

1. `$1.00 <= price <= $999,999.99`
2. Decimal place is not required (`$1` is valid as is `$1.00`)
3. Single digit post decimal place is invalid (`$1.1`, `$2.9`, etc..)
4. 3+ digits post decimal place is invalid (`$1.111`, `$2.999`, etc..)

The above pattern works to deal with the first two constraints but not the others. The issue being that in the case of **(3)** or **(4)**, the portion of the price that precedes the decimal point is matched.

Ex:

```
 $100,000.4 matches to $100,000
 $200,000.444 matches to $200,000.44
```

How can I modify this so that in the case of **(3)** or **(4)** the entire string is not matched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  Negative Lookahead `(?![\d.,])` to assert there is no digit, comma or dot following matched price:

```
\$[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})?(?:\.\d{2})?(?![\d.,])
```

[Regex 101 demo.](https://regex101.com/r/gY2eD6/3)

Answer (score 3):

Easy! Just add `([^,.\d$]|$)` in the end so the Regex parser should work until the nearest not a digit, comma, point, or dollar. Or it is already in the end of the string.

```
^\$[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\,\d{3})?(?:\.\d{2})?([^,.\d$]|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cS0fU6/5)

Comment: Is there a way to make it work such that if the prices are not necessarily seperated by whitespace? Like one price ends and flows directly into the next?

Comment: It will miss some occurrence because the dollar symbol $ of the next price is consumed by previous match.

Comment: Give the occurrence sample. And also please accept if it's right